# YouTube Api v3 - topic channel videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

So how do I get posted videos from a channel that is "auto-generated by YouTube" (topic)?
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSkJDgBGvNOEXSQl4YNjDtQ/videos

I can get topic ids from channel call but when I search by this topic ids I get a completely different results.

And if I run search api call with:

```
{
  'part':'snippet',
  'channelId':'UCSkJDgBGvNOEXSQl4YNjDtQ',
  'topicId':'/m/03lty'
}
```

I get only playlists and channels. No video results.

Comment: Did you ever get a satisfactory resolution to this? I have the same issue.

Comment: At this time there still isn't any reliable source of "upload". You can get close with playlists but it is not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this way:

- get the channel id in your case 'UCSkJDgBGvNOEXSQl4YNjDtQ'
- call playlists endpoint and retrieve the id

  GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?part=id&channelId=UCSkJDgBGvNOEXSQl4YNjDtQ&maxResults=1&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
- call playlistitems using the retrieved id

  GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId={RETRIEVED_ID_COMES_HERE}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

This works like a charm to me.

--
editing on March 27, 2016.
You can also scrapy how search engine does. Just check the ToS and Policy.

Comment: This works only for normal channels, not auto-generated channels.

Comment: it works for me. you have the playlists not uploaded videos.

Comment: Yeah, I need videos as well.

Comment: you cannot get directly uploaded videos from channel that has not uploaded any video. You can only get auto-generated playlists that have an aggregation of videos. the api hasn't provided a kind of functionality. Instead of go through the uploaded videos go through channels and then videos. The playlists probably contain the same order of auto-generated channel videos.

Comment: There are a bunch of videos in auto-generated channels. There are no playlists at least in some cases. I need to get the videos in that channel. How do I get them if there are no playlists?

Comment: Man, It's auto-organized by youtube I could post my code here but I don't have time for it. Sorry. When I get some time I post for you guys. Good luck with it. I can guarantee you can do it. Not in a tradicional way but you can. It's less flexible then not generated channels using youtube api. Another way is doing by crawling as search engine does (bing, google, linked, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Videos featured in an auto-generated channel are not created (uploaded) by this channel, so they don't show up in search results restricted to this channel id.

You can however get a list of videos associated with the topic by removing the channelId parameter.

EDIT: You can also do subsequent calls to retrieve videos for each playlist published by the auto-generated channel, with calls like this: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet&playlistId=PLfY-m4YMsF-OSodOIoTKPVblnYvdjU2Tn&_h=7&

Comment: By removing channelId I don't get anything close to results that are shown here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCSkJDgBGvNOEXSQl4YNjDtQ/videos

Can this videos even be searched somehow?